# Compilation gives "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" for cuda kernel call

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm stepping into the world of CUDA with a first example: computing Pi.
Unfortunately something went wrong and I can't understand why.

I've started from a working code for CPUs, then, with a few changes (added `__global__`, changed `new` into `cudaMallocManaged` and adding angular brackets at the kernel call) I've tried to run the same code on GPU. 
My purpose is to run a single instance on GPU, I know that the actual code is not parallelized.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>

#define NLIM 100000000

__global__
void compute_r(int *mem, double *rand_real, double *rand_imag ) {

    for (int i=0; i<int(NLIM); i++) {

        if ((sqrt(rand_real[i]*rand_real[i] + rand_imag[i]*rand_imag[i])) <= 1.0f) {
            mem[i] = 1;
        }
        else
            mem[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << "Refine Pi using " << NLIM << " iterations" << std::endl;

    double pi;
    int inner=0;
    int *gpu_inner;
    double *rand_imag; double *rand_real;
    cudaMallocManaged(&gpu_inner,sizeof(int)*int(NLIM));
    cudaMallocManaged(&rand_real,sizeof(double)*int(NLIM));
    cudaMallocManaged(&rand_imag,sizeof(double)*int(NLIM));

    for (int i=0; i<int(NLIM); i++) {
        rand_real[i] = double(rand()) / double(RAND_MAX);
        rand_imag[i] = double(rand()) / double(RAND_MAX);
    }

   compute_r<<1, 1>> (gpu_inner,rand_real,rand_imag);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i=0; i<int(NLIM); i++) {
        inner += gpu_inner[i];
    }

    pi= 4.0f* (inner/double(NLIM));
    std::cout << "Pi is " << pi << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled the code simply with `nvcc -std=c++11 main.cu` on an Amazon EC2 cluster with GPU support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cuda call needs to look like `compute_r<<<1, 1>>> (gpu_inner, rand_real, rand_imag);`. With just two '<' or '>' characters, the compiler figures you're trying to do a bitshift operation and complains.